# Which mountain range was formed first (historically) and which the pedigree is correct?

Tags: evolution, homework

Source 1:
[image]

Source  1 shows a map of a particular area. In this map you will find the  mountain ranges 1 and 2, the species P, Q and R. Two possible pedigrees of  the ancestral history of the species P, Q and R are drawn .
Which mountain range was formed first (historically) and which  pedigree is correct?

Comment: 1 might have formed first and I think pedigree 1 is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If mountain range `1` was formed first, pedigree `1` is correct.

If mountain range `2` was formed first, none of the two pedigree seem correct.

If mountain range `1` was formed first you would first have the split of the initial population into population `P` and the population `Q+R`. Then, the formation of mountain range `2` split the population `Q+R` into `Q` and `R`. Therefore, `Q` and `R` are more closely related than they both are to `P`. Therefore Pedigree `1` is correct.

You can apply the same kind of reasoning by guessing that mountain range `2` was formed first and you will realize that you would expect a pedigree different than Pedigree `1` and Pedigree `2`. If mountain range `2` appeared first then, the correct Pedigree would display the population/species/lineages `P` and `Q` more closely related to each other than they both are to `R`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think so?

Comment: @user4847 Update! Does it make sense to you?

Comment: I approve it....